# Need to Vlookup a specific phrase in a cell, and then go find another value in another table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Thanks for the assistance in advance!

I've got a table filled with campaign data. I need to write a function to look at a column "IO number" in Sheet 2, Column A, in this example "AM262" and then go see in Sheet 1, Column C if that name appears. In this example it does, but it looks like this "IO-AM262". If should then go to Sheet 2, and find the corresponding exchange rate in C2, and return it.

SO, look at S2, CA, and find it in S1, CC, and return S2, C1.

More complicated example: Find KP1002 in S2, A40 in S1, C24 (text: 2020|Q2|Sage|MEA|ZA|Small|Social_SMBS_KP1002) and return R14.95 in S2,C40)

Answer (score 1):

INDEX/MATCH might be the one you are after...

Assuming the following,

- Sheet headers are in Row 1 in both Sheet1 & Sheet2
- You are having a dataset ranging up to 100 rows in Sheet2

Please copy and paste the below formula in an empty column alongside the first data row in Sheet1

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$100,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$100)),0)
```

Press `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER`

Copy down the formula as required.

Comment: some nice answers today ! welcome to SuperUser

Comment: thank you so much for this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Can I email you a sample of the data?

Comment: @MariusGreeff - You can send me a dropbox file share link in here. I will sure check it out and respond.